# Graphing data in munin, need to ignore already seen values

Tags: munin, rrdtool

I am trying to graph how many ms a REST command is taking. The command is issued many times a minute. Here is the plugin that I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# Collect stats for the timing of recommendations.
#
logs="/var/www/custhome/logs/play.log"

# CONFIG

if [ "$#" -eq "1" ] && [ "$1" = "config" ]; then
        echo "graph_title Post Recommendation Times"
        echo "graph_category apache"
        echo "graph_info Data is pooled from all sites."
        echo "graph_vlabel ms"
        echo "graph_period ms"
        echo "graph_data_size huge"
        echo "precs.label PostRecommending"
        echo "precs.type GAUGE"
        echo "precs.min 0"
        echo "precs.draw AREA"
        exit
fi

# DATA

precs=(`grep :Post.Recommending /var/www/custhome/logs/play.log | awk '{print $7}'`)

for i in "${precs[@]}"
do
        [ $i -eq 0 ] && continue
        echo "precs.value $i"
done
```

This is what a typical bunch of lines looks like in the log file:

```
4:59:17,422 DEBUG ~ colorado:45870:Post Recommending took 1925 millis
15:02:22,588 DEBUG ~ michigan:417550:Post Recommending took 1306 millis
15:02:23,753 DEBUG ~ michigan:417550:Post Recommending took 276 millis
15:02:23,754 DEBUG ~ michigan:417550:Post Recommending took 277 millis
15:05:21,047 DEBUG ~ chicago:1105784:Post Recommending took 2484 millis
15:07:02,275 DEBUG ~ colorado:66199:Post Recommending took 3303 millis
```

The problem is, the graph is showing the same exact data every time it refreshes - 1.53k ms. This number appears to be an average. What I want to see is a graph that shows all of the values, and it needs to change over time as new data comes in.

Is there a better way to do this in munin? Or some preprocessing that I should do on the data first? Or a different tool entirely to see the results that I need? I'm used to using munin to graph things like the total number of REST calls per second. But I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around how to represent this data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this by averaging for each read:

```
for i in "${recs[@]}"
do
    ((total+=$i))
done

echo "recs.value $((total/${#recs[@]}))"
```